# sudo cron -l -u otheruser gives authentication error CentOS-6.10

Tags: cron, centos6, pam

CentOS-6.10

I have never run into this before:

```
sudo crontab -l -u thatuser
[sudo] password for thisuser: 

Authentication service cannot retrieve authentication info
You (thatuser) are not allowed to access to (crontab) because of pam configuration.
```

Why can I not list (or edit) another users crontab as root?

Comment: Rather than using sudo with a crontab command you can try and see what happens when you first start a root login shell (for instance with `sudo -i ` ) and then run `crontab -l -u username` - also auth errors are logged so check your logs for more info

Comment: Check your log files `/var/log/cron` and `/var/log/secure` for relevant entries.